# Does $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\|f_n\|_{C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le c$ imply that $\|f\|_{C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le c$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $n\ge 1$, $\alpha, s\in (0, 1)$ and let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_n \to f$ a.e. in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$\|f_n\|_{C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le c,$$
where $c$ denotes a positive constant.
Here
$$\| \cdot\|_{C^\alpha} = \|\cdot\|_\infty + [\cdot]_s,$$
where $[\cdot]_s$ denotes the usual Gagliardo seminorm.

It is true that $f\in C^{\alpha}$ and $\|f_n\|_{C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le c$ with the same constant $c$?
If yes, how to prove that?

I would say that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=\lim_n |f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le c |x-y|^{\alpha}$$
but I do not know how to prove the desired norm estimate.
Could anyone please help in that?

Comment: You should probably avoid naming both the dimension and the index of the terms of the sequence $n$.

Comment: Does $\alpha$ intervene at any point? I presume $s$ and $\alpha$ are supposed to be equal here?

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $x,y,z$ be so that $|f(z)|+\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}\geq \|f\|_{C^\alpha}-\epsilon$. Show that the left-hand side is $\leq c$ and then take $\epsilon\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x,y,z$ you have
$$
|f_n(z)| + \frac{ | f_n(x)-f_n(y)| }{|x-y|^\alpha} \le c.
$$
By Arzela-Ascoli theorem, for all $R>0$  the convergence $f_n \to f$ is uniform on $B_R(0)$.
Then take $x,y,z \in [-R,R]^d$ and pass to the limit in the above inequality.
This implies
$$
|f(z)| + \frac{ | f(x)-f(y)| }{|x-y|^\alpha} \le c
$$
for all $x,y,z \in B_R(0)$. The number $R$ is arbitrary, so the inequality is true for all $x,y,z$, which is the claim.

The trick of this reasoning is that the points $x,y,z$ are fixed during the passage to the limit. So there are no double limits involved.

Comment: daw, thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify where the $[\cdot]_s$ is used? Also, why does the first inequality hold true? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I used the standard norm of Hoelder spaces,  i.e., $\|f\|_{C^\alpha}:= \sup_x |f(x)| + \sup_{x\ne y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$. Not sure, why you would want to use Gagliardo seminorm with another parameter $s$.